# Apply error style to dynamic element in a data table jsf

Tags: jsf-2

I have a richfaces data table iterating over a list of objects.
The problem that I am facing is that when I try to apply error style to an inputText field, the error highlighting is being applied to the element across all the rows. I am using something like this :

```
styleClass="#{component.valid ? '' : 'ux-form-field-error'}"
```

Somehow the above code works fine for a date picker. The error highlighting only happens to the particular element.

Kindly help.

```
<rich:dataTable var="procLine" rowKeyVar="rowkey" 
                            value="#{claim1500FormBean.procedureLineList}" id="procLineTable">
    <rich:column>
        <rich:calendar maxlength="35"
        styleClass="#{component.valid ? '' : 'ux-form-field-error'}" 
            id="plStartDate">
        </rich:calendar>

         <h:inputText id="plProcedureCode" onchange="removeNonAlphaNumericChars(this);"
            styleClass="#{component.valid ? '' : 'ux-form-field-error'}" 
            value="#{procLine.procedureCode}" maxlength="8" onkeypress="return alphaNumericOnly(event);">
        </h:inputText>
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

"plProcedureCode" is the element to which style is not being applied the way it is supposed to.
Whereas "plStartDate" is a calendar component to which style is being applied in a specific row.

Comment: Not every elements have `valid` attribute, show the entire element code (the one with the non working *styleClass*)

Comment: I have updated my previous post.